# Classpath issue with eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am facing a very weird situation where I have a current project in which I have for e.g. a property file called abc.properties which is on the classpath. I also have a dependent maven project built locally which also has a property file abc.properties on the classpath. Now when running the application through eclipse debugger, it is using the dependent projects property file and not the one from the current project because of which my application fails to launch.

Any ideas on how to have eclipse use the property file from the current project and not the dependent one?

Comment: ["I" is always uppercase in English.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163).

Comment: Why have the same name?